# StartSSL Free Certificate and Plesk, https connection still unsecure

Tags: certificate, https, ssl-certificate, plesk

I'd just installed my certs correctly into my Plesk 8.3.0, I encountered some trouble with the "CA didn't sign the certificate" warning message but I solved it.

Right now it seems to me that I installed certs in the right way for my domain, but... Chrome, Firefox, they still saying that the cert is expired and auto-signed... I really don't know how to fix it.

On Firefox I got this message:

> Il certificato non è attendibile in quanto autofirmato. (autosigned)
>
> Il certificato è valido solo per plesk. (plesk valid only)
>
> Il certificato è scaduto il 04/03/2009 13:01. La data corrente è 22/04/2011 10:00. (no more valid)
>
> (Codice di errore: sec_error_expired_issuer_certificate) (error code)

I checked the server date/time and it's everything OK, anyway, this seems to me that Plesk didn't "catch" the new cert...

Some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply forgot to assign the Certificate to the static IP address, as can be readed here: http://kb.parallels.com/1736

> After you created or uploaded new
>   certificate into Plesk and wish to use
>   it for domains you should set it for
>   every IP you need, so domains use it
>   when you access them via HTTPS. It can
>   be done on page Server -> IP Addresses
>   -> "choose IP" by selecting needed Certificate in "SSL Certificate" drop
>   down menu.